# How to model the hilt of a sword?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm kind of new to blender, I've started trying to make some swords, I'm not too bad but I need help with modeling some objects such as:

[image: sword hilt]

I just don't know how I should go about making them or how to give them the desired form without making them look absolutely horrible.

Comment: Your image is too small not not very elucidative of the desired object. It also seems to be a 2D illustration which doesn't really translate unequivocally to a 3D object. Could you maybe post a screenshot of what you have so far and where you failed.

Comment: I just don't really know how I should try to make it, I don't know where to start or what to do after that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the curved, tapered and twisted hand protection part? This may be modeled using Bezier or NURBS curves. One curve defines the general curvy outline of the hand protector, a second the cross section (which looks a bit flower-like). This shape can be beveled along the first curve. Moreover it can be tapered and also drilled (tilted) to get the desired shape. Please look it up in tutorials on curve modelling; there are also some basics in the Blender manual (Curves, Beveling, Tapering, Tilt). - Greetings from Suthern Germany, Tschöbbel

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the time ive noticed, when people model things, they do it in parts.

Example, that sword would look pretty complex and frustrating all at once, so you could try and model the handle first, then model a moon-like shape thats near the blue sphere seperately, then duplicate those moons and slightly change the size & shape of them to suit/fit the image, if you know what I mean.

(or create the moons as drawn-on flat plane textures)

Im no pro, so I most certainly could be wrong; just thought I'd give a possible suggestion based on my observations.

Hope I helped 1 way or another!

Hope for the best!!